# How to pass Date as parameter?

Tags: apex, date

I am trying to create new opportunity passing 3 arguments into a method. how do I pass date since it is one of three required fields? Below is what I have at the moment.

```
public static void createNewOppty(String oName, string oStage, Date 
                                    ocloseDate){
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.name = oName;
        opp.stageName = oStage;
        opp.closedate = ocloseDate;
        insert opp; 
}
```

When I call the method what do I pass as date?

```
OpportunityClass.createNewOppty('500 bags','prospecting', /*how do I get the date here*/);
```

Comment: You should read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) about the `Date` class in Apex. There are various ways to instantiate a `Date` type. For example: `Date.newInstance(year, month, date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `system.today()` in the parameter.

```
OpportunityClass.createNewOppty('500 bags','prospecting',system.today().addDays(N));
```

Where N is the number of day you want to add in the today's date.

Comment: Would really recommend using date methods such as `addDays(N)` over relying on overloaded operators.

Comment: @battery.cord yes that would be a better option. Thanks.

Comment: What was the point of downvote here ?

Comment: I didn't. I actually accepted your answer and upvoted. N Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to Execute method from anonymous block, we can't pass date directly to any method.

first we need to create instance of `date` in anonymous block only

```apex
date ocloseDate = date.newInstance(2022, 9, 30);
```

then pass `ocloseDate` in method call

```apex
OpportunityClass.createNewOppty('500 bags','prospecting', ocloseDate);
```